# How Do I build a Multivariate Time Series Model With Inputs Having Different Time Frequencies?

Tags: r, time-series, multivariate-analysis

Working in R, I am seeking to build a time series model in the taxi industry.

My model is seeking to predict total miles in future time periods as a function of (1) miles in past past time periods and (2) housing starts in past time periods.

My data can be simulated as so:

```
library(ggplot2)

miles <- rnorm(36, mean = 100, sd = 12)
miles_ts <- ts(miles,start=c(2015,1), frequency = 12)

housingstarts <- rnorm(12, mean = 300, sd = 12)
housingstarts_ts <- ts(housingstarts,start=c(2015,1), frequency = 4)

autoplot(miles_ts)
autoplot(housingstarts_ts)
```

I would like a month by month forecast.  As you can see, my miles data is a monthly series whereas my housing starts data is a quarterly series.

To build the model, I will use the dLagM package in R.

My questions are:

1. Do I need to concern myself with converting my housing starts data to a monthly series as part of my pipeline?
2. If yes to #1, how would I go about doing this in R?  I've read about cubic spline interpolation - should I be using that?  With what code?